# Rails3: Expected admin/items_controller.rb to define ItemsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

The following causes unexpected exception:

```
Expected app/controllers/admin/items_controller.rb 
to define ItemsController
```

```
Foo::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :items

  match '/admin' => 'admin/overview#index', :as => :admin
  namespace :admin do
    resources :items
  end
end


% cat app/controllers/admin/items_controller.rb
class Admin::ItemsController < Admin::BaseController
end

% cat app/controllers/admin/base_controller.rb
class Admin::BaseController < ActionController::Base


% cat app/controllers/items_controller.rb
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
end
```

It worked for me in the Rails 2.3.5.

What might be wrong the code? How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the error this particular time, but I have run into it in the past. From memory, there are two things you can do:

- Go to the Rails console (`rails console` in your application directory) and type in `ItemsController`. The error message, if any, should be useful.
- One hackish fix that I've used is to load `items_controller.rb` before Rails start to autoload the controllers. You can either prepend the `config.autoload_paths` array with the path, or you can add a manual `require` to somewhere in your `application.rb`.